# Generating list until certain condition is met using a single line

Tags: python, haskell, generator, list-comprehension

I've been trying to 'further' my one-lining of stuff, and stumbled upon this bit. Simply using a while would suffice if I didn't forbid myself from using multiple lines.

So the sample problem I'm trying to solve is as follows (found it on one of those coding sites: codercharts, codeeval etc.):

> The problem is as follows: choose a number, reverse its digits and add it to the original. If the sum is not a palindrome (which means, it is not the same number from left to right and right to left), repeat this procedure.

Super simple, right? A simple while would suffice, but I don't really know how to generate numbers until a certain condition is met. I've checked out `itertools.takeWhile` and `itertools.dropWhile`, but those work with existing lists, which I would still have to generate.

I tried out generators, which work, but I don't know how to compress those in a single line.

Argh, in Haskell creating an infinite list and then using takeWhile would work, but in Python I'm stuck. Any pointers to the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:
To be more concise, I'm trying to do this on a single line (minus imports, of course).

Comment: Is this a python question or a Haskell question? And what *is* the question, exactly?

Comment: "Argh, in Haskell creating an infinite list and then using takeWhile would work, but in Python I'm stuck" - I think she wants Python!

Comment: Maybe a recursive lambda function?

Comment: Python can produce an infinite generator too; what would your haskell list produce?

Comment: It's a Python question. I'm aware Python is able to produce infinite generators, but I was wondering whether this was possible using only a single line of code. Not practical, I know, but hey it's for fun. (:

Comment: @JackieXu Shouldn't this belong in http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ with all the stringent conditions?

Comment: @JackieXu Also, can you please show how this can be done in Haskell? So, that we can try and port it to Python :p

Comment: @thefourtheye Ugh, you're right. Should've posted it there. I'm not sure how I move this (contact a mod?), and I don't want to double post this. As for the Haskell version, it's also a multi-liner. My mind just hadn't caught up yet as it was still stored there as 'done'. Thing is, I'm trying to move over to Python. :C

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs in http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ah, thanks! Did the same thing. And thanks for the codegolf mention, I 've never actually been there, but it appears to be loads of fun! (:

Comment: @JackieXu Do you want to see a two line solution, excluding input getting line?

Comment: @thefourtheye In Haskell, using 253 as example input, you could do `let rev = read.reverse.show in until (\x -> x == rev x) (\x -> x + rev x) 253` or if you use the Applicative instance for functions, `let rev = read.reverse.show in until ((==) <*> rev) ((+) <*> rev) 253` or with the Monad instance, `let rev = read.reverse.show in until (rev >>= (==)) (rev >>= (+)) 253`.

Comment: If it's a Haskell question the answer is trivial.  Write any code you like and then turn it into one line using {;}.

Comment: @augustss That's true in Python too and even more so in a language with whitespace of uniform meaning. I think we can interpret one-liner to exclude the use of `;` in this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd begin by writing this in a recursive fashion:

```
def frob(x):
    if str(x) == str(x)[::-1]: 
        return x
    else:
        return frob(x + int(str(x)[::-1]))

print frob(29)
```

Then, since a lambda can't refer to itself by name, I would remove the explicit recursion and require the user to pass the function to itself as a parameter.

```
def frob(f, x):
    if str(x) == str(x)[::-1]: 
        return x
    else:
        return f(f, x + int(str(x)[::-1]))

print frob(frob, 29)
```

This allows you to write `frob` as a one-liner.

```
def frob(f, x):
    return x if str(x) == str(x)[::-1] else f(f, x + int(str(x)[::-1]))

print frob(frob, 29)
```

Which can then be made into a lambda function.

```
frob = lambda f, x: x if str(x) == str(x)[::-1] else f(f, x + int(str(x)[::-1]))

print frob(frob, 29)
```

You can use a [fixed point combinator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator) to modify the function's signature, so that it no longer requires you to pass itself in explicitly.

```
frob = (lambda f: lambda x: f(f,x))(lambda f, x: x if str(x) == str(x)[::-1] else f(f, x + int(str(x)[::-1])))
print frob(29)
```

At this point, you no longer need the assignment at all, and can call the lambda in one line.

```
print (lambda f: lambda x: f(f,x))(lambda f, x: x if str(x) == str(x)[::-1] else f(f, x + int(str(x)[::-1])))(29)
```

---

Edit: I just noticed I misread the original problem statement - it's necessary to add the number to its reverse at least once, even if it's originally a palindrome. In that case, we can still use the same function, but we'll have to wrap it in something that executes that first step.

```
def troz(x):
    return frob(x + int(str(x)[::-1]))
```

Which reduces to:

```
print (lambda x: (lambda f: lambda x: f(f,x))(lambda f, x: x if str(x) == str(x)[::-1] else f(f, x + int(str(x)[::-1])))(x + int(str(x)[::-1])))(29)
```

Comment: Holy. Snap. This is beautiful. I've never worked with fixed point combinators, but now I'm definitely interested!

Comment: Another approach would be to use `accumulate`, e.g. `next(dropwhile(lambda x: str(x) != str(x)[::-1], accumulate(repeat(z+int(str(z)[::-1])), lambda x,_: x+int(str(x)[::-1]))))`.  But there's no point to it, as it's greatly inferior to a simple loop.

Comment: "*Then, since a lambda can't refer to itself by name*" I think this works (please correct me if I am wrong): f = lambda x: 1+f(x). By definition it stops being a lambda function but you can write it in one line.

Comment: You're right about that. I guess I should qualify it as, "a lambda that hasn't been assigned to anything can't refer to itself by name"